# Does Google Analytics match or filter the traffic with the domain given in the account?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

When you setup a google analytics profile and you specify the domain, does google make any sort of validation prior of registering a hit?

Does it check that the call comes from the specific domain, based on the key you are provided (ie UA-11580xxxx-xx)?

If I get the above analytics key and put it in another domain, will the hits on that site be registered for the domain for which the key was generated?

Thanks

Comment: There is an easy way to find out... paste it in another domain and check the traffic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort of.

By default, Google Analytics accepts hits to your account without ever checking where it comes from, so you could register your domain as foo.com, and still forever send traffic from bar.com without any trouble (or from a mobile app, etc).

However, Google provides an optional validation tool that will crawl the page of the website you provide, in order to validate whether or not you installed it correctly. But usage of this tool is optional, and is not a prerequisite for successfully sending and receiving data.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it does. I dynamically generate my Analytics JS code just from the key, and, when I've put the wrong one in, I'm pretty sure the traffic appears to go to the wrong site.

I'll re-test one of my sites to make sure...

Answer (score -1):

When you put the analytics code in the bottom of your HTML(with the key you got from google), first day you don't see anything, because Google is then already counting all visits on your website. after a day you can see result from the previous day.

Comment: Hi Tricker. Well, that's not what I am asking actually. I want to know if google matches the profile key with the domain

Comment: sorry wrong understanding. but no, because your code: UA-11580xxxx-xx
is specially for your domain. Google registers it.